# IndentationError: expected an indented block Analyze() Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, indentation

I'm using python and when i call my function it gives me this:

```
  IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Error, this is pretty frustrating because i have checked all the tabs and  it looks fine! What is the problem, can anyone help me, it seems like a simple and dumb problem but it is not going away!

```
Analyze()
```

At the bottom is the thing highlighted when the error is thrown!

Heres my code (i'm coding a Jarvis AI):

```js
#JARVIS mark 12  python 3.5.1 version
#JUST.A.RATHER.VERY.INTELEGENT.SYSTEM.
##import speech_recognition
##import datetime
##import os
##import random
##import datetime
##import webbrowser
##import time
##import calendar 
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import PunktSentenceTokenizer


#Brain functions, vocab!

what_i_should_call_someone = [""]

Good_Things = ["love","sweat","nice","happy","fun","awesome","great"]

Bad_Things = ["death","kill","hurt","harm","discomfort","rape","pain","sad","depression","depressed","angry","mad","broken","raging"]

Static_Greetings = ["hey","hello","hi","hey there","hi there","hello there"]

Sample_questions = ["what is the weather like","where are we today","why did you do that","where is the dog","when are we going to leave","why do you hate me","what is the Answer to question 8","what is a dinosour"]

possible_question_key_words = ["what's","what","where","when","why","isn't","this","that","what","is"]

Chance_that_question_was_asked_1 = 0

Chance_that_question_was_asked_2 = 0

certainty_question_was_asked = 0

Me_statment_keywords = ["you","your","yours"]

You_statment_keywords = ["i","i'm","me"]

global certainty_person_is_talking_to_me

the_last_thing_i_said = ("")

the_last_thing_person_said = ("")

what_person_said = ("")

what_person_said_means = [""]

what_im_about_to_say = [""]

why_im_about_to_say_it = [""]

who_im_talking_to = [""]

how_i_feel = [""]

why_do_i_feel_the_way_i_do = [""]

what_i_am_thinking = ("")

# ways to describe the nouns last said
it_pronouns = ["it","they","she","he"]

# last person place or thing described spoken or descussed!
last_nouns = [""]





while "Conversation":


    what_person_said = input()

    what_person_said1 = what_person_said.lower()

    what_person_said_wt = word_tokenize(what_person_said1)

        # try to define/name each word in the sentence! if the sentence is not as long as 9ish words it will except so it doest throw a index error!

             # word one in sentence 
    try: 
        word1 = what_person_said_wt[0]
    except IndexError:
        pass

             # word two in sentence
    try:
        word2 = what_person_said_wt[1]
    except IndexError:
        pass

             #sentence three in sentence
    try:
        word3 = what_person_said_wt[2]
    except IndexError:
        pass

    try:
        word4 = what_person_said_wt[3]

    except IndexError:
        pass

    try:
        word5 = what_person_said_wt[4]

    except IndexError:
        pass

    try:
        word6 = what_person_said_wt[5]

    except IndexError:
        pass


    try:
        word7 = what_person_said_wt[6]

    except IndexError:
        pass

    try:
        word8 = what_person_said_wt[7]

    except IndexError:
        pass


    try:
        word9 = what_person_said_wt[8]

    except IndexError:
        pass


    try:
        word10 = what_person_said_wt[9]

    except IndexError:
        pass


    try:
        word11 = what_person_said_wt[10]

    except IndexError:
        pass

    try:
        word12 = what_person_said_wt[11]

    except IndexError:
        pass


    try:
        word13 = what_person_said_wt[12]

    except IndexError:
        pass


    try:
        word14 = what_person_said_wt[13]

    except IndexError:
        pass


    try:
        word15 = what_person_said_wt[14]

    except IndexError:
        pass



    try:
        word16 = what_person_said_wt[15]

    except IndexError:
        pass


    try:
        word17 = what_person_said_wt[16]

    except IndexError:
        pass

    try:
        word18 = what_person_said_wt[17]

    except IndexError:
        pass

    try:
        word19 = what_person_said_wt[18]

    except IndexError:
        pass

    try:
        word20 = what_person_said_wt[19]

    except IndexError:
        pass



        def Analyze():

            def Analyze_for_question():
                        # problem i'm having is that the "for loop" devides by word and the keywords might be two words in a string seperated by a space, either
                        # i have to make all the question keywords one word or figure out how to fix this problem a different way!!
                for words in what_person_said_wt:
                    global Chance_that_question_was_asked_1
                    Chance_that_question_was_asked_1 = Chance_that_question_was_asked_1 + 1
                    if words in possible_question_key_words:
                        print (words)
                        print (Chance_that_question_was_asked_1)

                # This part will take the sentence and compare it with sample questions!

                Analyze_for_question()


            def Analyze_for_answer():
                # figure out if the last thing jarvis said was a question

                # if last_thing_i_said == Question:
                    # def Look_for_answer():








            Analyze()
```

Comment: Your definitions of and calls to function `Analyze()`, `Analyze_for_question()`, and `Analyze_for_answer()` are badly misindented.

Comment: ``Analyze_for_answer`` is empty. add a ``pass`` there or something.

Comment: @Grimmy Sry... But you were right: there is not a single statement in `Analyze_for_answer()`.

Comment: @DYZ dammit. Reverted back to normal now.

Comment: so what do i do guys!? Analyze is being called there its not empty!

Comment: In case you did not notice, function `Analyze_for_question()` calls itself, but does not call `Analyze_for_question()`, which is probably wrong.

Comment: @techset A tip is not to use functions inside functions like you are currently doing. It can make sense, but not in your code.

Comment: @techset also you never seem to break out of the while loop. There are many thing in your code you can greatly simplify and probably end up with a 1-2 page-script.

Comment: Really, could you tell me more about how i'd simplify it, it is complicated but the whole program is and it is going to only get more and more complicated so it needs to be a certain way to be able to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions cannot be empty in python. Lines commented out is not valid content.

This will give you an IndentationError:

```
def test():
    # comment
```

To solve it you need to add a `pass`. ("do nothing command")

```
def test():
    # comment
    pass
```

One exception is when you have a docstring.

```
def test2():
    """This is a test"""
```

here `pass` is assumed.

Answer (score 0):

### Your problem is in `def Analyze_for_answer()` (line 232)

This function is empty, remove the comments or the function, or add one line with the word 'pass' and the problem will be solved.

**Tip: Lower case for functions names**

Comment: Ok thank you. That was obvious, python should make errors less confusing!